# How to find Office 2013 installation path programmatically?

Tags: windows, registry, office-2013, installation-path

I'd like to find the installation path of Office 2013 programmatically.

I saw in [this discussion](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/efe946bd-25d0-4a30-9f8d-04ef2624d040/office-2013-win8-check-registry-if-installed) that the method working for Office 2007 and 2010 (looking in the HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\InstallRoot registry key) doesn't work anymore for Office 2013 and that the best way is to look into the registry keys

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{91150000-0011-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}

for Windows 32-bits or

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{91150000-0011-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}

for Windows 64-bits.

Is this supposed to work on every computer and for all versions of Office 2013 (Small business, Professional, etc) and Windows (7 and 8)? Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.
You can check uninstall registry key to get office install path.

As you mentioned registry key:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{91150000-0011-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
```

`{91150000-0011-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}` is like a product guid, you can treat it as a pattern to retrieve office path, I think they will be same installed on win7 or win8.
However, about different office version Small business, Professional... The guid may be same or different which depends on office implementation, you need to double confirm.